# Can anyone tell me why the use of pop() in my evaulateExpression is not working?

Tags: java, data-structures, expression-trees, postorder

Only worried about getting the first test done in the Test Class since the root of the tree is an operator "+" and its are operands/"children" are 3 and 4. Since the root is "+" I want to pop the left child and right child and push the node to the stack. Trying to understand why I cannot use the pop() method from the Stack class.

Node Class

```
public class Node < E > {
 E data;
 Node < E > left;
 Node < E > right;

 public Node(E data) {
  this.data = data;
 }

 public Node(E data, Node < E > left, Node < E > right) {
  this.data = data;
  this.left = left;
  this.right = right;
 }

 public String toString() {
  return data.toString();
 }

}
```

ExpressionTree Class
import java.util.Stack;

```
public class ExpressionTree {
 Node < String > root;

 public void buildTree(String expression) {
  Stack < Node < String >> s = new Stack < Node < String >> ();

  String expArray[] = expression.split(" ");
  for (String st: expArray) {
   switch (st) {
    case "+":
    case "-":
    case "*":
    case "/":
     Node < String > right = s.pop();
     s.push((new Node < String > (st, s.pop(), right)));
     break;
    default:
     s.push(new Node < String > (st));


   }
  }

  root = s.pop();
 }

 public void printExpression() {
  printExpression(root);
  System.out.println();
 }

 private void printExpression(Node < String > n) {
  if (n != null) {
   printExpression(n.left);
   System.out.print(n);
   printExpression(n.right);
  }
 }

 public int evaluateExpression() {

  return evaluateExpression(root);
 }

 public int evaluateExpression(Node < String > n) {
  Stack < Node < String >> s = new Stack < Node < String >> ();
  n = root;
  if (n == null) {
   return 0;
  } else {
   if (n.data.equals("+")) {
    s.pop(n.left);
    s.pop(n.right);
    s.push(n);
    evaluateExpression(n);
   }
  }
  return 0;
 }

}
```

Test Class

```
public class ExpressionTreeTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ExpressionTree et = new ExpressionTree();
  et.buildTree("3 4 +"); //infix: 3 + 4
  et.printExpression();
  System.out.println(et.evaluateExpression());

  /*et.buildTree("3 4 2 * 1 5 - / +"); //infix: 3+4*2/(1-5)
    et.printExpression();
    System.out.println(et.evaluateExpression());

    et.buildTree("3 4 5 * 2 / +"); //infix: 3+4*5/2
    et.printExpression();
    System.out.println(et.evaluateExpression());

    et.buildTree("12 8 + 6 5 - * 3 2 - 2 3 + * /"); //infix: (12+8)*(6-
    5)/((3-2)*(2+3))
    et.printExpression();
    System.out.println(et.evaluateExpression());*/


 }

}
```

Comment: Why use `Stack` when you already have a tree? also, `n = root;` in `evaluateExpression()` throws away the argument's value...

Answer (score 1):

As of the code

```
s.pop(n.left);
s.pop(n.right);
```

As the [Stack API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) shows, the pop function does NOT take any parameter.

It "[r]emoves the object at the top of this stack and returns that object as the value of this function."

You should use another class if you want to remove a specific object instead of whatever is on the top of the stack.